# RestSharp AddJsonBody is Not Serializing Body Correctly

Tags: c#, http, post, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp 106.11.7.

I'm trying to create a task on ADO. I'm using RestSharp as follows:

```
  var body = new AdoRequestBody
  {
    op = "add",
    path = "/fields/System.Title",
    from = null,
    value = "Sample task"
  };

  var request = new RestRequest("aStringPointingtoApi", Method.POST);
  request.AddJsonBody(body);
```

With this, the body is being serialized to:

```
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample task"
  }
```

According to [ADO API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#create-work-item) this is the correct body:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample task"
  }
]
```

I tried the body with array/list parenthesis in Postman and it's working. If I remove the array/list parenthesis it doesn't work.

This is the error message I get:

```
You must pass a valid patch document in the body of the request.
```

Someone here seems to have found a solution using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert, which I don't want to use.
https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1413#issuecomment-578302527

So, how do I get RestSharp to serialize my object inside an array parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API expects an array of `AdoRequestBody` objects and you are serializing a single object. As stated in comments, create an array with your single object, then serialize it for the request:

```
var body = 
  new AdoRequestBody[]
  { 
    new AdoRequestBody
    {
       op = "add",
       path = "/fields/System.Title",
       from = null,
       value = "Sample task"
    }
  };

 var request = 
  new RestRequest(
    "aStringPointingtoApi", 
     Method.POST);
 
 request.AddJsonBody(body);
```